# Mobile Stack Overflow- navigation flaw in the unanswered questions facilities (plural)

Tags: discussion

If I go to stackoverflow.com in my mobile, I see the list of all questions. I can choose to filter these to 'unanswered'.

What I then see is a list of questions where no answer has a green tick, either because there are 0 answers or because the OP didn't tick one of the posted ones.

I was specifically looking for no-answers questions though and there didn't seem to be an obvious way to do it from the main site.

In the end I found via Google that there exists another "site": stackoverflow.com/unanswered

This seems like a separate kind of question list specifically for unanswered where one can specify a no-answers filter. I call it another site, because there really doesn't seem to be any obvious way to get to it from stackoverflow.com.

So my question is, why was this so hard to get to? Why didn't choosing "unanswered" filter initially auto redirect me to /unanswered? If choosing "unanswered" on the main list shows the "what SO feel most users mean when the seek unanswered Qs" then what do users need to do to navigate to the dedicated subset of questions at /unanswered from stackoverflow.com?

I appreciate that unanswered and no-answers are different things and if unanswered has many flavours or applicable filters then maybe it should be a separate subsection of the site, but why then maintain the unanswered filter on the main question list, which is a less useful facility than the dedicated unanswered section provides?